# How to send emails from my personal email account (i.e Outlook.com domain) to external recipients using an SMTP server with OAUTH2

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, smtp

I'm developing a Third-party email client (like Thunderbird for instance) that functions properly with basic authentication. In this method, users enter their email credentials and I use Jakarta Mail in Java to authenticate their credentials and connect with the SMTP server (smtp.office365.com). However, I want to incorporate an oauth2 authentication approach.

As a result, I registered an app in AzureAD and redirect users to it to acquire the access-token. However, when I attempt to connect to the smtp server in AzureAD using the XOAUTH2 mechanism, the authentication fails, but authentication with Office365 domains within the tenant is successful. I need to be able to connect to the smtp server as an external user. There seems to be a missing component, and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the Azure AD app registration supports [Microsoft personal accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps#who-can-sign-in-to-your-app). If it does not, set it's app manifest [signInAudience attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#signinaudience-attribute) to `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount` or `PersonalMicrosoftAccount`.

If that does not solve the issue come back with detailed error information.